# Using NpgsqlDataAdapter for insert with returning clause

Tags: npgsql, dataadapter

I use NpgsqlDataAdapter (Npgsql 3.0.5) to insert new rows in a table. The primary key value for the new rows is created by the database, therefore I want to pass it back to the application. Therefore I generated an InsertCommand with proper parameters as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TASK_JOURNAL(TJ_ID, TJ_COMMENT, TJ_COMPLETION_STATE) 
  VALUES(ID_GENERATOR.GenerateId('TASK_JOURNAL'), :p0_TJ_COMMENT, :p1_TJ_COMPLETION_STATE RETURNING TJ_ID, UPDATED_ON)
  INTO :p11_TJ_ID, :p19_UPDATED_ON
```

However, it seems that Npgsql is not prepared to accept return values in a DataAdapter.InsertCommand, I am getting the following error:

> Parameter ':p11_TJ_ID' referenced in SQL but is an out-only parameter

Call stack:

```
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.SqlQueryParser.ParseRawQuery(string sql = "INSERT INTO NET_UT.TASK_JOURNAL(TJ_ID, TJ_COMMENT, TJ_COMPLETION_STATE) VALUES(NET_UT.ID_GENERATOR.GenerateId('TASK_JOURNAL'), :p0_TJ_COMMENT, :p1_TJ_COMPLETION_STATE) RETURNING TJ_ID, UPDATED_ON INTO :p11_TJ_ID, :p19_UPDATED_ON", bool standardConformantStrings = true, Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection parameters = {Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection}, System.Collections.Generic.List<Npgsql.NpgsqlStatement> queries = Count = 0) Line 127  C#
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ProcessRawQuery() Line 504  C#
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.CreateMessagesNonPrepared(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = SequentialAccess) Line 563 C#
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ValidateAndCreateMessages(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = SequentialAccess) Line 555 + 0x12 bytes    C#
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderInternal(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = SequentialAccess) Line 914   C#
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = SequentialAccess) Line 901 + 0xe bytes   C#
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) + 0xf bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateRowExecute(System.Data.Common.RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent = {Npgsql.NpgsqlRowUpdatedEventArgs}, System.Data.IDbCommand dataCommand = {Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand}, System.Data.StatementType cmdIndex = Insert) + 0xbe bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(System.Data.DataRow[] dataRows, System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping tableMapping = {System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping}) + 0xa88 bytes 
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(System.Data.DataRow[] dataRows) + 0x13c bytes
```

I know this could be achieved by using NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader instead, however, not using NpgsqlDataAdapter would require changing all my framework which I am also using for Oracle (which accepts returning parameters in Insert and Update).

I am interested if there is a solution using NpgsqlDataAdapter to return values in an insert statement.